# Merging two lists into dictionary while keeping duplicate data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Hi, I want to merge two lists into one dictionary. Suppose I have two lists such as below

list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']

list_two = [1,2,3,4]

and I want my dictionary to be like this

```
{'a': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

As of right now, I have this following code

```
print dict(zip(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd'], [1,2,3,4]))
```

But the output from above code is this

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

How can I make it to this output?

```
{'a': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is simply impossible.

Comment: @Julien Maybe not in Python with its dictionaries, but dictionaries with duplicate entries for the same key are possible. Balanced trees like Red-Black can handle it and provide range queries, like find the lowest or highest duplicate key, etc.

Comment: @Kaz, maybe but here OP is talking about python dict...

Comment: @Julien I see, so is there any way in python that I can do a mapping function to get my desired ouput like above?

Comment: This simply is impossible because your question makes no sense: as said by @Sebastian what is the mapping of `'a'`??? `1` or `2`? or should it be `[1,2]`? you need to clarify...

Comment: @IqbalPratama if you've ever used another data structure such as a hashtable, the python dictionary follows the same principles.

Answer (score 8):

Since keys in dictionaries are unique, getting `{'a': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}` is impossible here for regular python dictionaries, since the key `'a'` can only occur once. You can however have a key mapped to multiple values stored in a list, such as `{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}`.

One option is to create a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do this easily for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']

list_two = [1, 2, 3, 4]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(list_one, list_two):
    d[key].append(value)

print(dict(d))
```

Which outputs:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}
```

Answer (score 6):

A defining characteristic of `dict`s is that each key is unique. Thus, you can't have two `'a'` keys. Otherwise, what would `my_dict['a']` return?

Comment: The question "what would `my_dict['a']` return" actually has some reasonable answers. A requirement can be given in this area, for a dictionary that is intended to support multiple entries. C++ has a `std::multiset` dictionary type which supports a `find` function and `[]` indexing. Basically these return one of the duplicate keys; it is not specified which. There is a reliable way to iterate over the whole range of duplicate keys. I.e. a rhetorical question suggesting that a requirement is not reasonable isn't really the answer; it's just not the way a `dict` is in Python, that's all.

Comment: Ah I see, so then this would be impossible to do right?

Comment: @IqbalPratama  Impossible *directly*. However, the Python `dict` certainly can be used to write code which associates multiple values with the same key. Just associate keys with lists of values rather than values. Concretely speaking, `{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}`.

Comment: @IqbalPratama depends on what you would want `my_dict['a']` to return.

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries must have unique keys, so you would have to change your requirement. How about a list of tuples as a workaround?

```
l = list(zip(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd'],[1,2,3,4]))
print(l)
```

With the resulting being:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

You can easily iterate over and unpack like so:

```
for k, v in l:
    print("%s: %s" % (k, v))
```

which produces:

```
a: 1
a: 2
c: 3
d: 4
```

If you want it hashable, you can create a tuple of tuples like so:

```
l = tuple(zip(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd'],[1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: it's getting an error -> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to create a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options :

either you use tuple :

```
list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']

list_two = [1,2,3,4]



print(list(map(lambda x,y:(x,y),list_one,list_two)))
```

output:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Second option is use this pattern:

```
dict_1={}

for key,value in zip(list_one,list_two):
    if key not in dict_1:
        dict_1[key]=[value]
    else:
        dict_1[key].append(value)

print(dict_1)
```

output:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'd': [4], 'c': [3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, **with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)**. A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way dictionaries are written on output.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary has unique keys. If you need the value of 'a' separately store the zipped data in a list or you can use list in values part of the dict and store the values as:
{'a': [1,2],'c': [3], 'd': [4]}

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, dictionaries have unique keys, however, it is possible to create a structure to mimic the behavior you are looking for:

```
class NewDict:
   def __init__(self, *values):
       self.values = list(zip(*values))
   def __getitem__(self, key):
        return [b for a, b in sorted(self.values, key=lambda x:x[0]) if a == key]
   def __repr__(self):
       return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, "{"+', '.join("{}:{}".format(*i) for i in sorted(self.values, key=lambda x:x[0]))+"}")

list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
list_two = [1,2,3,4]
d = NewDict(list_one, list_two)
print(d['a'])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
NewDict({a:1, a:2, c:3, d:4})
```

Comment: Wow. +1 for this awesome creativity.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in dictionary should be unique.

According to python documentation:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

[link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
to the documentation